# não consigo usar o emulador de android no androidstudio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, máquina-virtual, intel

Boa Noite pessoal, eu preciso rodar o android studio na minha máquina, mas ele da o erro:
 "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. VT-x is disabled in BIOS. Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for your computer)."

pelo oq eu saiba, é necessário ativar a virtualização na placa mãe. Porém não tem essa opção na Bios do meu notebook.

alguem sabe oq pode ser?
eu entrei no site da intel e pelo oq parece o intel i3-2328M tem suporte a VTX
(https://ark.intel.com/content/www/br/pt/ark/products/70927/intel-core-i3-2328m-processor-3m-cache-2-20-ghz.html)

Answer (score 0):

O documento de especificações técnicas do produto contém mais informações. Clique no nome do seu produto de Produtos relacionados para ver a documentação e a página inicial do seu produto.

https://www.intel.com.br/content/www/br/pt/virtualization/virtualization-technology/intel-virtualization-technology.html

Você pode habilitar ou desabilitar a Tecnologia de virtualização Intel® na configuração da BIOS. O comportamento padrão é "desabilitada". Para alterar as configurações, faça o seguinte:

Acesse o BIOS do sistema pressionandodurante o POST ("power-on self test" - autoteste de inicialização).

Clique em Advanced > Processor Configuration.

Configuração do processador

Selecione Intel® VT for Directed I/O (Tecnologia de virtualização Intel® para E/D dirigida) e mude para Enabled (Habilitada).

Selecione a Tecnologia de virtualização Intel® VT e mude para Habilitada

Execute um ciclo de desligamento-religamento da alimentação CA.

Nota    Sempre que as opções de configuração são mudadas para "habilitada" ou para "desabilitada", é necessário executar um ciclo de desligamento-religamento da alimentação CA ("power cycle") para que as alterações entrem em vigor.

As placas para servidor Intel® ou os sistemas servidor Intel® precisam dos seguintes componentes para suportar a Tecnologia de virtualização Intel® ou a Tecnologia de virtualização Intel® para Directed I/O:
Processador Intel® Xeon® que suporta a Tecnologia de virtualização Intel®
BIOS com suporte para a Tecnologia de virtualização Intel® ou a Tecnologia de virtualização Intel® para Directed I/O
Também pode ser necessário um gerenciador de máquina virtual (VMM - virtual machine manager) de terceiros.

Answer (score -2):

sua maquina tem que possuir suporte a virtualizacao, creio que processadores i3 nao tem e se tiver voce deve entrar no BIOS e ativar a virtualizacao.